# Correctness of Propagating Cipher Block Chaining mode of operation (PCBC)

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, modes-of-operation

I was looking at [the Wikipedia article about Block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Propagating_cipher_block_chaining_(PCBC)) and I was wondering how can you from the encryption $C_i = E_K(P_i \oplus P_{i-1}\oplus C_{i-1})$ get the decryption $P_i = D_K(C_i) \oplus P_{i-1}\oplus C_{i-1}$ ?

Is there even a way to get decryption from encryption  (and vice versa)  or not?

Comment: Take the encryption equation, apply $D_K$ to both sides, solve for $P_i$.

Comment: @Mikero Ok, but what is $D_K( E_K(P_i \oplus P_{i-1}\oplus C_{i-1}))$? I'm a beginner and I have no idea what should I get from this.

Comment: Oh, $D_K (E_K ( x))=x$, doesn't it? Ok, then I know how to solve this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How the PPCBC mode works**

Propagating Cipher Block Chaining mode of operation (PCBC) works as with message indexes starts from 1;

- For PCBC encryption we have;

$$C_i = E_K(P_i \oplus P_{i-1}\oplus C_{i-1})\text{ and } \color{red}{C_0 = P_0 \oplus IV}$$

- For PCBC decryption ve have;

$$P_i = D_K(C_i) \oplus P_{i-1}\oplus C_{i-1}\text{ and } \color{red}{C_0 = P_0 \oplus IV}$$

given $C_1$ to decrypt $P_1$

$$P_1 = D_K(C_1) \oplus P_{0}\oplus C_{0} = P_1$$

given $C_2$ to decrypt $P_2$

$$P_2 = D_K(C_2) \oplus P_{1} \oplus C_{1}$$ Now we can solce since we know, $P_1$ and we have all $C_i$s.

and so on...

The red part was missing in your question.

---

**The Correctness of the PCBC mode**

An encryption scheme must satisfy **the correctness requirement**; for every key $k$ output by the key generation algorithm and for every message $m \in \mathcal{M}$ ($\mathcal{M}$ is the message space), the following must hold;

$$ D_k(E_k(m)) = m$$

---

To see that PCBC has the correctness; take

$$C_i = E_K(P_i \oplus P_{i-1}\oplus C_{i-1})$$ take decryption on the both sides

$$D_K(C_i)= \color{red}{D_K}(\color{red}{E_K}(P_i \oplus P_{i-1}\oplus C_{i-1}))$$ cancel Enc with Dec.

$$D_K(C_i)= P_i \oplus P_{i-1}\oplus C_{i-1}$$

Therefore:

$$P_i = D_K(C_i)  \oplus P_{i-1}\oplus C_{i-1}$$

Since we know, all $C_{i}$s, and previously decrypted $P_{i-1}$.

If it is the first case $(i=1)$, then we already know $\color{red}{C_0 = P_0 \oplus IV}$